# Having problem with Shared Reference in case of Lists

Tags: python, list

```
a=b=[1,2,3]
print (a is b) #True
```

But

```
a=[1,2,3]
print (a is [1,2,3]) #False
```

Why does the second part print `False` ?

Comment: This mighy helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: Because in the first example a and b are the same list. In the second you have two lists with the same content. `is` is not the same as `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple assignment in Python creates two names that point to the same object. For example,

```
>>> a=b=[1,2,3]
>>> a[0] = 10
>>> b
[10, 2, 3]
```

---

`is` can be used to check whether two names (`a` and `b`) hold the reference to the same memory location (object). Therefore,

```
a=b=[1,2,3]  # a and b hold the same reference
print (a is b) # True
```

---

Now in this example,

```
a = [1,2,3]
print (a is [1,2,3]) # False
```

`a` does not hold the same reference to the object `[1, 2, 3]`, even though `a` and `[1, 2, 3]` are lists with identical elements.

In case you want to compare whether two lists contain the same elements, you can use `==`:

```
>>> a=b=[1, 2, 3]
>>> a == b
True
>>> 
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a == [1, 2, 3]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first one explicitly makes `a` and `b` references to the object created by the list display `[1,2,3]`.

In your second code, *both* uses of the list display `[1,2,3]` necessarily create new `list` objects, because lists are mutable and you don't want to implicitly share references to them.

Consider a simpler example:

```
a = []
b = []
a.append(1)
```

Do you want `b` to be modified as well?

For *immutable* values, like `int`s, the language implementation *may* cause literals to reuse references to existing objects, but it's not something that can be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the logic operator you are using.
You are asking are these identical object with `is` and not if they are the equal (same data).
One is a reference to a object and the other is the object so even though they are equal the are not the same.

### Why your results

When you are setting `a` and `b` as the same list you are saying that `a` and `b` should be linked and should reference the same data so they are identical to each other but `a` and `b` are not the object `[1,2,3]` they are a reference to a list that is the same.

### In summary

`==` - equal to (same).

`is` - identical to.

So if you want to check if they are equal(same) use:

```py
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> print (a == [1,2,3])
True
```

Similar question worth reading: 
[Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Hope this helps, Harry.